# Relative Performance of Heap vs Reading Leftmost node of Map?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

Imagine you are a wholesaler and have customers who have customers. Transactions are done by your customer's customers, but while you see every transaction, you only bill your customers, and only have to worry about your customer's deposit being exhausted. This is a pre-paid service.

The transaction is for a service, the value of which is a function of the duration of the service * the rate.

I need a way of watching a 0-million of my customers' accounts for deposit exhaustion by aggregating the charges their customers' are accumulating. I have no financial arrangement with my customers' customers.

When a given service instance starts, the BurnRate of my customer increases as the charge rate of any given service is added to an accumulated rate for my all in-process services rendered on behalf of my customer. When service terminates, the BurnRate is likewise reduced.

A good candidate would seem to be a [min heap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/), or [priority queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/?kw=priority_queue), but it occurs to me that a conventional tree/map would also work, as the leftmost node, IE the first node read from an iterator, would yield the same information.

It's at least possible that N customers may have exactly the same moment of deposit exhaustion, AKA Time-TO-Live (TTL) calculated as "now" + (CurrentBalance/BurnRate), so a multimap may be more suitable than a heap. Again, any insight based on experience would be very helpful.

My primary question is **which has better performance**, the heap or the map/multimap?
Secondarily, will the heap handle duplicate values gracefully?

TVMIA for any performance insight, especially from experience or benchmarks.

**PS:** Reviewing the literature, I've omitted an important requirement. When new service is started, or in-process service is ended, I have to update the data structure with a delete of the customer's old TTL node, and insert a new node with the new TTL. **It appears a priority_queue does NOT support these operations.**

Also, In Chapter 31, page 924 of *The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition*, Stroustrup strongly hints that using a tree for priority_queue implementation is the preferred method. As my above "oops" requirement can only be satisfied by a tree, my choice is clear, so benchmarking will not be done to compare the two approaches - at least not until this project is completed.

Thanks all who've been in attendance (or lurking) and have shared their knowledge and experience.

Comment: First and foremost: Profile it. Find out. The answer will be unique for EVERY DIFFERENT computer in the world. Second: define gracefully as pertains to heaps handling duplicates.

Comment: Trees have poor memory performance than hashtables (Note that Im saying hashtable, not std::map. Map is a tree) because of cache misses. In a common use case I think its difficult to feel any performance issue, but you are talking about millions of customers. It could be a detail to be considered. In addition, trees have O(logn) complexity, and hashtables O(1). Again, in a common (little) use case, O(logn) its "pseudoequal" to O(1) (Note that log(1000) is 3). But in your case... Billions...

Comment: @Manu343726, thanks for the reply, but I'd have to know the size of the hash table needed up front to use hashes. My application doesn't allow this, thus trees are the only reasonable alternative. 

Just a reminder, O(1) is not necessarily faster than O(logN). These metrics do NOT indicate absolute performance, but only specify how the performance changes as the size of the searched set grows. IE: comparison between approaches is not specified, only the performance as a function of growth. This is why hashes can be slower than trees, not that they're an option in my case.

Comment: You are correct. I'm just pointing that in big use cases (As in your case), the cost would increase. But its true, that are not real performance metrics, are only performance increment/decrement metrics.

Comment: @jmucchiello, why would the answer be unique for every different computer? He's asking for the RELATIVE performance of two approaches. The relationship, whatever it is, should be the same across a wide variety of platforms.

Comment: @RocketRoy, heap performance is hard to measure in the general case. In specific cases, you can be very specific about the answer. But in general, it depends on how many buckets there are compared to how many entries there are and it also depends on how well the hash function is at providing unique results. Access to a heap is usually called O(1) while a tree is always O(log2(n)) for access. But the log2(n) of a tree is strictly comparisons. The O(1) of a heap is a call to its hash function and the complexity of the hash function can be greater than log2(n) for a given n....

Comment: ... Compares and jumps used in a tree can be fast if they all exist in the L1/L2 caches. Calculating a hash is faster if the entire object is in a cache but for a large object, that hash might be big. For a large tree used often in the program, the upper branches are more likely to be in local cache. It is extremely complex and every architectural decision in the design of the computer impacts the speed just like the size and quality of the hash algorithm chosen impacts the speed. Big O doesn't say enough unless you are talking about simple objects like ints being stored. Then is bigO good.

Comment: @jmucchiello, I agree, and make this point RE: O(1) and hash functions v.s. log2(N) all the time. I think I'm just going to have to try it both ways with some representative data and find out. Will report back with results, and maybe give myself the nod for answers if so. I'll tell the boss "Because 'J' said so!" ;)

Comment: @jmucchiello: you hash the *key* which you use for comparison... the whole object doesn't have to be in the cache.

Comment: @Karoly - your point being? A hash function can take more time than O(1) implies. That's my point. If you have string keys and do a bunch of logical op across the length of the strings, then O(1) actually is O(m) where m is average length of string key. For a small container that can easily be slower then O(logn). My point remains the same. If you want to know which of 2+ things performs faster, test that performance in your specific environment with your specific data. That's the only way to be sure you KNOW which way is faster.

Comment: I just noticed we're actually talking about a min heap. It has O(logn) complexity looking up the minimum value in the heap. Just like the Tree. So again, you really need to test it to see which works better for you.

Comment: @jmucchiello: my point was, you do the *comparison* also on the *key*. So if, as you said, the string length is m, then just comparing two elements in a heap (or any tree like structure) to decide which direction to go is O(m). So the total operation will be O(logn*m).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath In a tree, you run key1 < key2 log2(n) times. In a normal heap, you run hash(key1) once then, key1 == key2 m times, depending on how many buckets have more than one identical hash. The question about which is faster depends on how long it takes to generate the hash, normally not a short function, version doing a bunch of quick comparisons. That's my point about key length.

It is less relevant now though since we are talking about a min heap which has characteristics similar to a tree. Since they are both O(logn) you need to run both to determine which is better for your data.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, for example, a hash function to create an integer out of a long, variable length string might take 2,000 clocks, while a string compare might take 100 clocks on average. You'd have to do 20 compares to burn up as much time as doing the hash. That's a very large tree. In general OlogN (complexity) tells you, for a given data structure, how the access time changes as the size of the structure increases. It says absolutely nothing about the absolute time consumed, absolute time for any other data structure, or the relative performance of the two.

Comment: ok, I will stop the discussion here, it's pointless. You jumping from one topic to another, without even listening. 2000 clock is nothing compared to a cache miss, and you were talking about cache. What you wrote is all true, but you haven't taken the effort to react to what I wrote. In my dictionary that's not a "conversation".

Answer (score 0):

Since no actual data/architecture is provided, one can only discuss theory

Let us first define the 3 choices being used:

**heap** this, per the link you provided seems to be a sorted `vector`

**tree** this, by usage in the OP is `std::map`, which can be considered to be a red-black tree

**hash** generally, this is called a hash-map and has been incorporated into the STL as `std::unordered_map`

We will ignore one, verse multiple payloads (map vs multimap) because performance should not differ much

Since we are talking about *many* data points, we can look at the expected max time.  We can also look at amortized average time since you have not mentioned a response time limit, but more of a throughput limit.

The 3 operations that must be looked at are, insert, delete and find first (no requirement for random access has actually been mentioned)

For each collection/operation: average complexity/max complexity will be listed

```
collection   insert       delete     first
heap         N/N^2        N/N        1/1
tree         log N/log N  1/1        log N/log N
hash         1/N^2        1/N        1/N
```

Note that has has two problems

- all operations can become linear if there are too many collisions
- insert may require the storing array to grow

Heap has two problems

- insert and delete may cause most data elements to shift
- insert may require the vector to grow

It would seem of these data structures, hash has the best possible performance with an occasional really bad performance hit.  If this can be amortized (average as opposed to worst performance is critical) then use **hash**, otherwise for best worst case performance **map** does come closest to meeting the requirements.   If insertion/deletion time is not critical and can be isolated from impacting find first times, **heap** will be the fastest and likely provide the best locality.

And, as mentioned, you really should profile/stress test all solutions under consideration

Comment: As noted. Hash is not an option as the size of the hash table cannot be known.

Comment: @RocketRoy `std::unordered_map` does not require the size to be known, it grows the same way that `std::vector` does.

Comment: @ Glenn Teitelbaum, It only appears to grow. Behind the API it has to allocate a new, larger table, scan the old table, hash all entries into their new locations, then free old memory block. If insufficient memory, disaster.

For semi real-time systems like telecom, the 30-200 seconds required to do this "halt & sweep" operation is not an option, Thousands of customers would be waiting for a dial tone. Their reaction would be to hang up and place yet another call - repeatedly - until frustration set in. Disaster. Important to remember the API is an abstraction. A disadvantage of C++ vs C.

Comment: @ Glenn Teitelbaum, All of this ignores CPU costs of hashing. In real-world telco systems, events like 9/11 all hit the system at the same time, so you can't assume CPU, memory, etc is going to be available, and redials make everything much worse. Parsing calls is expensive. My solution was to write a CPS Throttle to choke off call floods. Very lean. Core code capable of 30+ million CPS on a single core. Embedded and real-time systems are a very different animal and require a much higher level of design & implementation. Still, you are technically correct. Kudos for pointing that out.